# Check if specific values in column follow each other for each id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-science

I have the following dataframe

```
id | status
____________
1  | reserved
2  | signed
1  | waiting
1  | signed
3  | waiting
2  | sold
3  | reserved
1  | sold
```

I want to chech a hypothesis that statuses `reserved`, `waiting`, `signed` always lead to status `sold`. I only need to check the following order, some statuses may be omitted like for `id == 2` in dataframe.

I wonder if there's a way to look for next row values in grouped by id dataframe

Expected output is dataframe or list of `id`s that follow the above rule. For the dataframe above it would be this:

```
id
__
1
2
```

My attemp was to get all unique `id` with those statuses and then for each `id` found list of it's statuses. Then I thought to filter it somehow but there are a lot of combinations.

```
df = df[df.status.isin(['reserved', 'waiting', 'signed', 'sold'])]

df1 = df.groupby('flat_id').['status'].unique()

df1.where('status'== [''reserved', 'waiting', 'signed', 'sold'']
or ['reserved', 'waiting', 'sold'] ... )
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output? To be clear what should happen if you had another group like 1 but with a different order of the items?

Comment: Sorry, but it's still unclear, how is id 2 following the rule? There is no reserved/waiting. Also, is order important?

Comment: @mozway, yeah, there is no reserved/waiting but it follows the rule because sighed followed by sold. Only the order (reserved, waiting, signed, sold) is important not the existence of all 3 statuses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you just want to check that 'sold' is the last value per group:

```
m = df.groupby('id')['status'].apply(lambda s: s.iloc[-1] == 'sold')
out = m[m].index.tolist()
```

output: `[1, 2]`

If you want to ensure there is something before 'sold':

```
m = df.groupby('id')['status'].apply(lambda s: len(s)>1 and s.iloc[-1] == 'sold')
```

And if you want to ensure that this something is in a specific list:

```
m = df.groupby('id')['status'].apply(lambda s: s.isin(['reserved', 'waiting', 'signed']).any()
                                           and s.iloc[-1] == 'sold')
m[m].index.tolist()
```

###### alternative:

```
(df.drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
   .loc[lambda d: d['status'].eq('sold'), 'id']
)
```

output:

```
5    2
7    1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```